# Use 'if' to check a condition. If condition is not met, then do not change the value in the cell. Keep the previous value as it is

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Cell B1 has value 1
Cell B2 has value 1

Cell B10 has no value.
I write 'if' formula: `B10` = `IF(b2=b1, b2,)`
The value in `B10` changes to `1`.

Now, I change `B2` value to `2`.
The cell `B10` changes to `0`. (because the 'if' conditon is not met).

But I want the if forumula to do nothing and keep the `B10` value same as before, i.e. `1`. 
I do not want to change `B10` value when 'if' condition is not met.

Please guide with the solution.

Comment: Just for grins try `=if(B2=B1,B2,B10)`.  Excel will probably spit it out, but maybe not.

Comment: When you write a formula in B10 you lose the value in that cell. I think you have to set the formula in another cell (eg C10 to have C10=(if(B2=B1;B2;B10))

Comment: This question is a little ambiguous and therefore unclear. If `B1` and `B2` both = `2` and therefore `B10` will be `2`. Do you want `B10` to equal `1` if you later change `B1` back to `1`?

Comment: If you want a formula to be based on what data *used* to be in the sheet instead of what's currently in the sheet,  you may be out of luck. It's entirely possible with VBA, though.

Answer (score 0):

After the second `,` in the `IF` statement you have to tell Excel what to do. If you want the B10 to be blank if the condition is not met, you will need to add `" "` to the statement after the second coma.

```
=IF(B2=B1, B2, "")
```

This will result in B10 remaining blank if B1 and B2 are not equal.